# GLES performance bottleneck in iOS 11 (seen on 6S+)

Tags: performance, opengl-es-2.0, ios11

**EDIT:** This is not a code bottleneck. Profiling shows identical CPU usage regardless of fluctuating GPU ms. Also I incorrectly talked about glbufferdata when I first posted; it's glbuffersubdata.

As part of an optimisation drive for the Android build of our app, I reorganised the render pipeline of our engine in a way that exposed a very significant performance bottleneck on certain iOS devices under iOS11.

Our engine manages a mixed scene of 2D geometry (UI) and 3D static models. The 2D geometry is dynamic, and generated each frame.

Until recently, every time a 2D draw call had to be issued (change in texture, change in blend modes or shader etc), the sprite data generated so far would be uploaded via glbuffersubdata and then rendered. This was fine on iOS, less so on Android.

To improve performance on Android I made the engine put all the 2D geometry into a single data buffer, upload it to a single VBO with one glbuffersubdata call at the start of the next frame, and then execute draw calls using sub-sections of that buffer. This led to a significant boost on Android devices, and made no difference to some of our iOS test devices (eg iPod Touch 6 running iOS10).

However, on a 6S+ running iOS 11, the new pipeline increased the GPU time from a rock-stable 8ms to a wildly-fluctuating 10-14ms, often pushing the game down to 30fps instead of 60. This is not the first time something previously innocuous has become performance-killing with an iOS update.

I've now made the buffering-up a compile option, and regained the lost performance on iOS, but if you are generating significant amounts of dynamic geometry and struggling with performance on iOS11, you may see an improvement if you stop trying to batch glbuffersubdata uploads and instead perform smaller ones interspersed with render calls.

Comment: You should use `glBufferSubData` instead of `glBufferData`, whenever possible, to avoid reallocating the memory. As for your issue, you should try profiling your code to see where exactly the problem is.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code. The code executes in the same amount of time regardless; it's the GPU time that fluctuates hugely. Also, I made a mistake when typing: we do use glbuffersubdata. I'll add that info to the post to avoid confusion. Thanks!